# Using python "requests" module in a cygwin64 ZNC module

Tags: python, module, cygwin, installation, python-requests

I'm positive that I'm doing something wrong, but I've looked around and the solutions presented have not worked for me.

I'm writing a bot for ZNC running under Windows 10/cygwin64 (which allows python based scripts). One of the functions I'm trying to write requires the "requests" python module, but when I try to run the python bot, it throws this error:

> ImportError: No module named 'requests'

I've tried placing the "requests" source in the same folder as the bot's .py file. I've also tried easy_install to no avail.

Oddly enough, I was toying around with another python module that was required, and it worked as soon as I placed it's source in the same folder.

The version of python that ZNC is running is 3.4.

**Edit:** I noticed that cygwin64 stores the python bins and libs for ZNC under a specific sub-folder. I've therefore installed the "requests" module under the relative lib/site-packages directory. I think it worked, as far as the module being visible, but now ZNC crashes as soon as I load that bot script. It throws this:

> cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to
>   znc.exe.stackdump

When I check that stackdump, it has the following:

> Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=001801A62CD

Comment: How are you importing requests? requests is a folder of code. Are you placing the entire folder into your location? Lots of times, under Windows, this issue is the PATH. You might need to do something like... "from my_module import requests" where my_module is the name of your module (and you have an __init__.py in there as well). I don't think requests has any system dependencies but I do not know for sure.

Comment: Thanks @RyanO'Donnell. I've tried something else (see edit in question) and got some brand new errors.